# Is a North Carolina driver’s permit also valid in South Carolina?

Tags: usa, driving-licenses, north-carolina, south-carolina

In both states, the required age is 15 to get a permit. Does that mean that a permit issued in North Carolina also allow you to drive legally in South Carolina?

Comment: Are you specifically talking about learners permits or full permits? I ask because it would be insane if you had to exchange a full NC permit for a SC permit each time you popped across the border...